# Rails - Create or Update Record .... If statement vs find or create by

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have

```
@user = User.find(1)
@event = Event.find(1)
for interest in @event.interests
  @user.choices.create(:interest => interest, :score => 1)
end
```

Working properly but it creates records every time.  I would like to check to see if a record with the corresponding interest_id from the for loop exist and if it does I would like to update, else creating is fine.

I looked around and found the "find_or_create_by" method but its not really working for me. I had =>

```
 @user.choices.find_or_create_by_interest(:interest => interest.id, :score => 1)
```

and get the error "undefined method `find_by_interest'".

Can you see what I'm doing wrong? Or is it better to stick with the an if/else statement?

I wasnt sure if the find_or_create_by method had the update attribute capability within it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once again, you should do `find_or_create_by_interest_id_and_score`

Comment: I get the error ... Unknown key(s): score, interest ??? Have you seen this before?

Comment: find_or_create_by_interest_id_and_score(interest.id,1). But BEWARE! If ever you have an object with the good id but the wrong score, it will try to create it and will fail: you can't have two objects with the same id.

Comment: yes...that is one way to do it, but its not updating the records that where found...its only adding if it cannot find a record....I'm starting to think that a if/else statement might be the best option

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaking on what you are trying to achieve the way to do it is:

```
find_or_create_by_interest_id(:interest => interest.id) { |u| u.score = 1 }
```